# UI5 Web Components and ObjectListItem

Tags: ui5-webcomponents

I am experimenting with UI5-webcomponents and Angular. I try making an application that has similar design with an existing OpenUI5 application that uses a list with `ObjectListItem` items. The only equivalent I found is `ui5-li` but it has very limited properties - `description` and `info` for texts. I need also `number` and `nubmerUnit` + some statuses.

Can I somehow achieve this preferably without custom css?